# Inline variable substitution in Model Builder using python code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, modelbuilder, parameters

I have an inline variable substiution which I would like to import into my Python script. Is that possible? I am trying to make a parameter within my path.

My path currently is "c:\Users\Jelle\Dropbox". Within Model Builder I can substitute 'Jelle' by using an inline variable subsitution (name) and call it through %name%. 
I would like to replace "Jelle" with other names but then within a Python script.

I have tried using GetParameterAsText and making the inline variable as a Parameter within Model Builder but I get an empty output: Here is the script which I tried for it:

```
import arcpy
username = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #this is the inline variable 'name' which I am trying to call
input_table = "C:\\Users\\"+str(username)+"\\Dropbox"
```

Input_table gives the following return:

```
"C:\Users\\Dropbox"
```

Hence the 'username' variable is not returned

I have the feeling I should be using something else other than GetParameterAsText. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: I think the issue is that I am not settung the parameter as this is already given as a variable within model builder while parameters within model builder would be used so that they can be adjusted when the model is being setup to run.

Comment: Are you trying to do this all in Python code or trying to include a Python script tool as part of your model?

Comment: I am trying to use Python code within a 'Calculate field' tool within Model Builder. So within the 'Calculate Field' tool I want to call for the inline variables that are present in my model.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question to include a simple test model and test script that illustrates the model/code pattern that you are trying to get working?  From that I suspect it will be easier to see what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your inline variable directly in the calculateField tool.

with a Python expression entered in the CalculateField tool, it would look like this:

```
"C:\\Users\\{}\\Dropbox".format(%name%)
```

The variable should be present in your model (right clic > create variable > Type = String). Here I renamed it "Name" and required it as a precondition, but this should not be necessary. Check this variable as a model parameter if you want users of the model to modify it from the form.

[image]

Comment: This seems like an answer to the right direction! It gets the inline variable ('Jelle') but now gives this error that this global variable is not defined. How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out what the issue was. If I use the script within my pre-code block, I need to define the variable %Name%. This is what I wrote in my script

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I figured out what the issue was. If I use the script within my pre-code block, I need to define the variable %name%. This is what I wrote in my pre-code block script:

```
def my_funcrtion():
import arcpy
my_name = "%name%"
fc = "C:/" + my_name + "/Dropbox/featureclass"
```